# Windows batch - access SET variables outside a routine

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, scope

I'm trying to parse a file version of the form 1.2.3.4 into its component parts.

say I have file ParseVersion.bat

I want to call it with

```
call ParseVersion.bat 101.102.103.104
```

and in return get four variables called v1, v2, v3 and v4

my attempt

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set Version=%1
set Version=%Version:.=,%

set j=1
for %%i in (%Version%) do (
  echo !j! %%i
  set /a j=!j!+1
  set v!j!=%%i  
)
endlocal
```

After calling this from another batch file, I want to be able to access `%v1%` through `%v4%` as environment variables.  I guess the problem is due to the `SET`'s inside a `setlocal` not persisting outside the `setlocal`, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `call` :

```
@echo off 
set "$count=1"
set "$var=%1"
for %%a in (%$var:.= %) do call:next %%a
echo %var1% - %var2% - %var3% - %var4%
exit/b

:next
set "var%$count%=%1"
set /a $count+=1
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick.  As an aside, for completeness shouldn't the `:next` subroutine end with a return to the caller (I realise that it is implicit here, but what if we had two subroutines in the file) ? What's the proper way to do a return?

Comment: The return is automatic inside a `for` loop if you have another `call` after the first one just put a `goto eof`at the the end of the subroutine.